# Transform retrieved livedata from different sources (storage, firestore) via Transformations

Tags: android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, picasso, android-livedata

**Following situation:**

I'm retrieving data from firestore via `LiveData` to display it in a `RecyclerView` like this:

`val placesDataSet: LiveData<ArrayList<Pair<String, PlaceModel>>> = db.getCollection("places")`

`PlaceModel` has a property `previewImageUrl: String` which will be passed to `Picasso` image library inside the `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

After retrieving the "place" information (which is an `ArrayList` of `Pair<documentId: String, place: PlaceModel` I want to get the `previewImageUrl` from Firebase Storage in the next step and map it to corresponding `PlaceModel` object before displaying it in the `RecyclerView`.

The storage data structure is as follows: `images/$documentId/preview_image.jpg` and therefore I need to get the place information (because of `documentId`) first to identify the right image folder.

How can I handle this using `Transformations`? I have also a function called `getDownloadUrl(path: String): MutableLiveData<Resource<String>>` which returns the downloadUrl for provided `path` from storage.

What I've tried till now is:

```
val dataSetFinalState = Transformations.map(placesDataSet) {
    mapDownloadUrl(it)
}

private fun mapDownloadUrl(arrayList: ArrayList<Pair<String, PlaceModel>>): 
 ArrayList<Pair<String, PlaceModel>> {
    arrayList.forEach {
        it.second.previewImageUrl = // How to call getDownloadUrl(path: String) here and wait for response?
    }
    return arrayList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortionally I couldn't solve this problem with Transformations so I decided to choose another approch. After uploading the preview image I try to get the download url to store this information into database.

The problem with this approch was that I use the image resize extension of firebase with delete original image option. Creating resized images takes a bit time so therefore I had an error in the next step because the image has not been existed. But I solved this problem with retry mechanism.